# Javascript changes window with navigator.language / navigator.userLanguage

Tags: javascript, window, navigator

I am trying to change the loaded window depending on the langues of the user.
I have used the following JS code but it doesn't seem to work and I have no idea why.

```js
    var lang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;

if(lang == "en") {
    window.location = "en"; //English
}
if(lang == "nl") {
    window.location = "nl"; //Dutch
}
if(lang == "ar") {
    window.location = "ar"; //Arabic
}
if(lang == "fr") {
    window.location = "fr"; //French
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!
Best regards.

Comment: edit: I put the above code in script tags in my header

Comment: Put a `console.log(lang);` statement before the `if` sequence to see what the value actually is. I suspect you're getting something like `en-US` or an equivalent for some other locale.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? As far as I know, "en" is not a valid URL.

Comment: you forgot the slash. ex: `window.location = "/en"`

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a clear problem statement.